# How can I count how many table rows are shown after filtering?

Tags: javascript, php, filter, rows

How can I count how many table rows are shown after filtering?

I've tried running this script, but it shows total rows, not currently shown rows:

```
function CountRows() {
    var rowCount = 0;
    var table = document.getElementById("filter_table");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
    var message = "Showing: " + rowCount;
    alert(message);
}
```

Location: http://kissbandstree.com/count_rows.js

There is no error message.

This is the filter script: http://kissbandstree.com/multifilter.js

This is the test page: http://kissbandstree.com/artists2.php

I want to show how many rows are showing after a filter has been applied.

This is the relevant PHP / HTML part:

```
<?php
// Fetch all filenames in the kiss_artists directory
$artists = glob('kiss_artists/*.txt');
?>

<table class="standard">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo"Items in table: " . count($artists) . ". Showing: XXX. Table is sortable. Artists names are links to simple individual pages. Date is when the entry was modified."; ?>
        <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="CountRows();">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How you are hiding the rows. Using `display='none'` or something else?

Comment: Good question. I'm not completely sure. There is something called row.hide(); in multifilter.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check all the count of visible rows only.. because by seeing that page, you are hiding rows that are not relevant to the filter.

I have to minus one count from total just because of header row was calculated too.

Also, Since you use jQuery in that page, this should be the simplest solution

```
function countRows(){
      let rowCount = $('#filter_table tr:visible').length - 1;
      var message = "Showing: " + rowCount;
      alert(message);
    }
```

Comment: That is so elegant, fast, to the point and brief. Works like a charm. Thank you so much! Updated with your code and works: http://kissbandstree.com/artists2.php. Now I shall try to move the number to "clickme" button to "Showing: XXX." text.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to skip the hidden rows by adding a check for visibility to your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].style.display == 'none') continue;
    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
        rowCount++;
    }
}
// for the header row
rowCount--;
```

Since there is a header row you need to subtract one from your count.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. I used the jQuery. I'm a lot closer now, thanks to you guys. Latest test: http://kissbandstree.com/artists3.php Basically just need to have the complete number shown on page-load now, instead of -1.